# How to use use ndb library schemeless

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

using datastore client library.
Can be used regardless of the state of the datastore property.

```
datastore_client.put({
  "foo":"foo",
  "bar":"bar",
  "xxx":"xxx", # any property can put
  ...
})
```

But, using ndb.
Only predefined properties can be used.

```
Class Test(ndb.Model):
  foo = StringProperty()
...
Test(
  foo="foo",
  bar="bar" # error
).put()
```

If I want to put()/get() schemeless.
I cannot use ndb?

Comment: Look for ndb.Expando. This is what you want

Comment: Thx! It looks like what I want to do! Please post Answer to ✓check your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for ndb.Expando .This is what you want